# set background image in table layout

Tags: tablelayout

i have used table layout for my one xml

i am trying to add one background image as follows:

```
 android:background="@drawable/myimg"
```

den i am getting error like

```
02-28 11:58:57.713: E/AndroidRuntime(850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.Scan}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.widget.TableLayout
```

i have even tried like following:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bkg1">

 <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1_tblLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1_tblLayout1_tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center" >


                ......

               </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>
           </LinearLayout>
```

then also i am getting same error.

please some one helppp me.!

Thank you.

Comment: i noticed one thing that, i am not able to set my background to any layout by using   android:background="@drawable/myimg"
i am getting same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry guyz , it was my mistake

i was using jpeg format's file.

when i used .png file.

i managed to solve my problem..

***YOU CAN SET ONLY .PNG FORMAT'S FILE TO LAYOUT***